# Facebook 4.7.0 LoginManager onCancel() constantly triggered

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Recently migrated from a 3.+ something version of Facebook SDK to 4.7.0. With this there are a lot of changes, this includes the `LoginManager`. I have some simple Login functionality on my app with registers a callback `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(..)`, then logs in with some read permissions:

`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"));`

The problem is every time I try to login it triggers `onCancel()` from the callback first time, and then I have to click sign in again which triggers `onSuccess()`. However, this doesn't happen via a browser - it's just using the Facebook app, so it seems like there is an internal problem there.

It feels like it accepts the permissions, calls `onCancel()` then the second time round it has already accepted permission and logs in successfully.

Has anyone been experiencing similar issues and found a solution? Or alternatively knows of any internal problems with the Facebook APK?

The device I'm testing on is a `Samsung S3 Mini`, if that helps.

Comment: we experienced this weird issue, where we were never able to get a token via the app.. we switched to web auth eventually

Comment: Are there any errors logged when onCancel gets called?

Comment: Have you tried any of the sample apps that ship with the SDK, and do you get the same behavior? Can you post more code and include any errors or logcat output?